# What would a War time Economy look like in a modern, first world setting?

Tags: warfare, aliens, economy

In this instance I'm kind of curious as to what a war economy would look like in a Modern first world nation like say Canada?

Overall what kind of shifts and changes would one expect from an economy that, whilst not totally mobilised, was being geared to fight what is the equivalent of Aliens on the ground that has similar tech levels to modern humans?

I'm using Hearts of Iron Terms where total mobilisation is one step above the war economy.

In this instance assume,  that about 40 million people are being killed out of 8 billion by the aliens.

Comment: You might want to specify how the aliens *get* to the ground, and *where* on the ground they are. If they've got a spaceship nearby or something, the "war economy" = mass producing nukes. If their ground forces are grouped up in places that are not near a lot of humans, the "war economy" = mass producing nukes.

Answer (score 3):

You specified that they are "not fully mobilized," which makes this difficult to answer. There are a range of options to pick from for your setting.

- Look at Russia, which seems to be in a semi-official stealth mobilization without *really* enacting the reserve call-up. They're also passing laws which require industry to take military contracts, on the government timetable. (I realize that the Soviet Union used to the the *Second World,* not the first. How to rate Russia is a debate in itself.)
- Similar laws are on the books in the West, this came up during the early days of Corona when the production of protective gear had to be ramped up.
- Think back half a century to Vietnam. There might have to be a draft. This might be less total than the WWII-era draft, which then opens options for well-connected individuals to dodge the draft while marginalized groups have to go. Also parallels to how Russia recruits "volunteers" today.
- Against extraterrestrials, how will the propaganda/home front angle play out? Think back two decades to the months and years after 9/11, general paranoia and acceptance of torture and other human rights violations. If the enemies are not even human, what is the political climate?
- On that note, various special interests will roll back environmental protections, etc., on grounds of the war. Even if they do not really matter for the conflict.